# Javascript - Programatically return near places by latidude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, geolocation, openstreetmap

Is it possible to get nearby places, providing the Latitude and Longitude?

If, for example, I would like places around the provided Lat, Long within the range of 50 kms, how do I go about achieving that?

Is there any algorithm / formula ?

I'm using [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) geolocations

Thank you.

Comment: i'm using openstreetmap geolocations

Comment: Check the openstreemap geolocation API reference, you will probably find something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below formula to calculate distance between two given co-ordinates:
(lat1, lon1) and (lat2, lon2)

```
dist = arccos(sin(lat1) · sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) · cos(lat2) · cos(lon1 - lon2)) · R
```

Reference: [Great-circle_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

Now lets say you have all these co-ordinates saved in database, then you can run a query to find all the locations that are within 50km of range.

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) * 6371 <= 50;
```

It is also possible to do this in Javascript. You need to use some Math functions and iterate through an array which stores the co-oridinate to check the distance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this formula to find the distance between 2 points based on lat/lng. You can then use it for your purpose:

```
var kmBetween = function(a, b){ 
    var e = Math, ra = e.PI/180; 
    var b = b.lat * ra, c = a.lat * ra, d = b - c; 
    var g = b.lng * ra - a.lng * ra; 
    var f = 2 * e.asin(e.sqrt(e.pow(e.sin(d/2), 2) + e.cos(b) * e.cos(c) * e.pow(e.sin(g/2), 2))); 
    return f * 6378.137; 
}

var distance = kmBetween({
                          lat: 45.5,
                          lng: 33.4
                         },
                         {
                          lat: 44.3,
                          lng: 32.4
                        });
```